# Magento 2 setStoreId VS setCurrentStore

Tags: magento2, price, scope

What is the exact(!) difference between:

- `setStoreId()`
- `setCurrentStore()`

Example where the two give different results.

```
// setStoreId solution    
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId(2)->load(1);
echo $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

VS

```
// setCurrentStore solution    
$storeManager->setCurrentStore(2);
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
echo $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

**EDIT:** I am getting different results when there is a catalog price rule active on just one of the two stores.

Answer (score 1):

`setStoreId` will load the data for your products for the scope of the store id if the attributes for your products have some store view values for it.

`setCurrentStore` will go to the next step; in fact, I would advise to use the `ProductRepository` to load the product data in your second snippet. But the benefit of this second option is to also return your price formatted with the currency of the store. IN your case you are querying the value and it would not make a difference.

In conclusion, it does depends on the context and because the needs you're having is to return the price raw value, then It may be the first option is very much what you'd need to keep it simple

**EDIT**: it turns out your question is very good. The function `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Collection::get` is what seems to split the behaviour of these 2 snippets.

In your snippets, both call the method `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getPriceInfo`, but their behaviour will split in this function; this method loads the catalog pricing rule for the current store using the method `\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Collection::get` and this method does use the storeManager; that is why the first snippet does not pick up the price rules; Now, you will notice as well if your 2 store views share the same website id, the price would be the same.

To be ideal, your final snippet should use the dependencies below:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,

    $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(Store::DISTRO_STORE_ID);
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($input->getArgument('product_id'));
            $output->writeln(
                sprintf('the sku: %s has a price of: %s',
                    $product->getSku(),
                    $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                )
            );
```

**EDIT2:**: I was about to forget, we are exploring 2 practices here. But there is a best practice when it comes to set the current store; the article https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-store-emulation/ explains quite well that there is more to it from what we have seen.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how both react to catalog price rules? I added this to my question. PS: we have tried product repository in the same context. Same results.